# Multiplication of $p$-adic integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

As I am reading Serre's *A course in arithmetic*, he defined $x\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ as an infinite sequence $x=(\ldots,x_n,\ldots, x_1)$ with $x_n\in \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ and $x_{n+1}\equiv x_n$ mod $p^n$ for all $n$. He then says *"multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is defined coordinate by coordinate"*. Does this mean
$$(\ldots, x_n,\ldots, x_2,x_1)\cdot (\ldots, x_n',\ldots, x_2',x_1')=(\cdots, x_nx_n',\cdots, x_2x_2',x_1x_1')?$$
Or maybe can someone give a clearer explanation of how multiplication works in $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Only the products are taken  modulo the corresponding powers of $p$. So that $x_nx_n'$ is in fact $x_nx_n'\mod p^n$.

Comment: If you are learning about $p$-adic number for the first time, I suggest looking at the initial  chapters of Gouvea's "$p$-adic Numbers".

Comment: I think Serre is good enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes indeed, you have understood correctly that this means
$$(\ldots, x_n,\ldots, x_2,x_1)\cdot (\ldots, x_n',\ldots, x_2',x_1')=(\cdots, x_nx_n',\cdots, x_2x_2',x_1x_1'),$$
where multiplication in eachthe $n$-th coordinate is multiplication in $\Bbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z}$, so if the $n$-th coordinates are $x_n,x_n'\in\Bbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z}$ then the $n$-th coordinate of the product is $x_nx_n'\in\Bbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z}$. Note that the product again satisfies $x_{n+1}x_{n+1}'\equiv x_nx_n'\mod{p^n}$ for all $n$.

This construction of the $p$-adic integers is an example of an [inverse limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit), which is a very general way of creating a new (larger) object from a partially ordered collection of (smaller) objects with morphisms between them.

Another way to view $p$-adic integers and their arithmetic, is to view a $p$-adic integer $x=(\ldots,x_n,\ldots,x_2,x_1)\in\Bbb{Z}_p$ as an 'infinitely long' integer in base $p$
$$x=\ldots+a_np^n+\ldots a_1p+a_0=\sum_{k\geq0}a_kp^k,$$
with $a_n\in\{0,\ldots,p-1\}$ such that for every $n$ you have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kp^k\equiv x_n\pmod{p^n}.$$
Then multiplication of two $p$-adic integers $x$ and $x'$ is the same as for regular integers, except now infinitely long:
\begin{eqnarray*}
xx'&=&\big(\ldots+a_np^n+\ldots a_1p+a_0\big)
\big(\ldots+a_n'p^n+\ldots a_1'p+a_0'\big)\\
&=&+\ldots\big(\sum a_ka_{n-k}'\big)p^n+(a_0a_1'+a_1a_0')p+a_0a_0'.
\end{eqnarray*}
This can again be expressed in the form $xx'=\sum_{k\geq0}b_kp^k$ with $b_k\in\{0,\ldots,p-1\}$ after writing each coeficient $\sum a_ka_{n-k}'$ in base $p$, and carrying over where necessary.

Another way to construct the $p$-adic integers is as the ring of integers of $\Bbb{Q}_p$, the $p$-adic numbers, which is the completion of $\Bbb{Q}$ with respect to the $p$-adic absolute value defined by $|x|_p=p^{-n}$ if $x=p^n\tfrac ab$ with $a$ and $b$ coprime to $p$. But the arithmetical properties of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ are not as immediate from this perspective.

Comment: Thank you so much! When you define the $p$-adic absolute value, is it really necessarily to be $p^{-n}$ or it can also be $e^{-n}$? I just asked because I have also see people using $e$ as the base.

Comment: Yes, you are right; any base would make it an absolute value. But with the base $p^{-1}$ the absolute value also relates nicely to other absolute values. For starters, you get for every $x\in\Bbb{Q}$  that
$$\prod_p|x|_p=1,$$
where the product ranges over all primes, inluding the 'infinite prime' corresponding to the usual absolute value (yielding the completion $\Bbb{Q}\subset\Bbb{R}$). This statement generalizes nicely to number fields (and beyond). So I recommend sticking to this base.