# Is 2/9 = 0 in 2-adic?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

If my math checks out we have that the 2-adic integers:

$$...0101010101 = 1 + 4 + 16 + ... = 1/(1-4) = -1/3$$

and

$$...1010101010 = 2 + 8 + 32 + ... =  2/(1-4) = -2/3$$

(which makes sense to me because multiplying by 2 "shifts" a 2-adic number left.)

Since [p-adic multiplication is done component-wise](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3850930/42677), I expect:

$$...1010101010 × ...0101010101 = ...0000000000$$

Analogously we would have that:

$$-1/3 × -2/3 = 2/9 = 0$$

I tried to check my work by writing out the expansion of $2/9$, but:

$$\frac{2}{9} = \frac{2}{(1-(-8))} = 2 - 16 + 128 - 1024 + ... =$$ equal to what? I don't know how to deal with the negative terms.

Is $\frac{2}{9} = 0$ in $2$-adic?

Comment: Study the information in your link carefully. You are working in a ring of characteristic $0$.

Comment: "Componentwise" does not mean "digitwise".

Comment: Yes, this example illustrates one hazard of thinking of $p$-adic numbers as having a sort of $p$-power expansion with coefficients mod $p$... Yes, they can be expressed as such, but addition and multiplication do not behave according to an overly-optimistic hope. :)

Comment: Incidentally, you may observe that in $2$-adic, $x$ and $-x-1$ are complements of each other (in your question, $x = -1/3$), and yet we don't conclude $-x^2-x = 0$ for all $x$. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The product ...0101 times ...1010 should be computed in column, in the usual way:

```
...0101 * 0 =  ...0000000
...0101 * 1 =  ...010101 
...0101 * 0 =  ...00000  
...0101 * 1 =  ...0101   
            .            
            .            
-------------------------
            =  ...1010010
```

the result, if carefully computed, should be $\frac 2 9$.

Answer (score 5):

As a way to check the direct multiplication given in Emanuele Paolini's answer, you can compute

$$
-\frac19 = \frac{7}{1-64} = \ldots000111000111
$$

We can subtract this from $0$ to get

$$
\frac19 = 0 - \left(-\frac19\right) = \ldots111000111001
$$

and then shift to double, yielding

$$
\frac29 = 2\left(\frac19\right) = \ldots1110001110010
$$

which is indeed the result of the direct multiplication given in Emanuele's answer. Note that multiplication by $1001_2 = 9$ gives just $10_2 = 2$.